# Run NSTimer method in background

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, nstimer

I am trying to run a method on NSTimer of 30min. But when i press home button of iPad, the method is not called in background. The method is user to hit the server and get the response. I want the method to be called only after 30min, in background.. Is there any way to do it in iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask =0;
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
```

Comment: Maximum time the application can be in background is 3min, >= iOS7.. 

I want my method to run in background after 30min.

according to your code you are ending all background tasks.